# differentiate between folder or file in aws s3Client.listObjectsV2 response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm creating a lambda application in node js to find all the files in s3 folder.

I'm using `s3Client.listObjectsV2` to fetch all the keys in s3, I'm getting the below response, I want to filter the resultset to just files. whats the best practises for the same.

```
{
      Key: 'AttributeModel/',
      LastModified: 2021-12-16T23:47:54.000Z,
      ETag: '"d41d8cd98f0"',
      Size: 0,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
    },
    {
      Key: 'AttributeModel/173b8566-5033-4606-a087-ba93ef2c1467.json',
      LastModified: 2022-01-06T17:34:29.000Z,
      ETag: '"d41d8cd98f0"',
      Size: 68,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
    },
    {
      Key: 'AttributeModel/009d155e-e45d-48a7-9a30-19cabb61479b.json',
      LastModified: 2021-12-17T04:02:36.000Z,
      ETag: '"d41d8cd98f0"',
      Size: 48,
      StorageClass: 'STANDARD'
    }
```

Comment: They are all objects. When you click "Create Folder" in the S3 management console, it actually creates a zero-length object with the same name as the directory. This causes the 'directory' to appear in S3. Therefore, your code could simply ignore any entry with `Size: 0`.

Comment: hey @JohnRotenstein, I believe you can create file with 0 bites.  would your suggestion still work then?

Comment: You asked how to filter the result set to just "files". They are _all_ files. If you don't want to show the pretend 'directories', you can simply skip over the zero-byte objects. If you want to keep zero-byte objects that aren't 'directories', then do what @upender recommends and ignore entries with a slash (`/`) at the end of the `Key`.

Comment: how about this ? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-the-given-path-is-file-or-directory-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Are all the files `.json`? or do you know what are file extensions you will get?

If yes, then you can filter based on whether the `key` has an extension or not.

```js
 const filteredData = dataReceived.filter(eachItem => eachItem.key.endsWith('.json')
 console.log(filteredData)
```

You can add **OR** condition in `endsWith` method if you have more extensions

**Another Method:**

```js
 const filteredData = dataReceived.filter(eachItem => !eachItem.key.endsWith('/')
 console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: yeah but I need to modify the code each time. trying to avoid that.

Comment: Then you can build the logic based on the key value of the folder. Every folder name ends with `/`.

Comment: Added the 2nd method in the answer.

Comment: I'm planning to go with https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-the-given-path-is-file-or-directory-in-node-js/  reason being, don't know how the above code works in x86 vs ARM architecture, we can offload that to the library.

Comment: If you are already using that (file system) package in the code its fine. But if you are installing the package for this alone. Better to go with our custom code to improve performance and memory.